# Code after Process.Start() call not running, but working when debugging C#

Tags: c#, process

Here is the function that is calling `Process.Start()`.

I am simply opening two folders in WinMerge. This part works correctly and this application pops up. None of the code written after this runs though. However, when I place a breakpoint on `p.Dispose()` or `p.Start()` and press continue, everything afterwards works correctly.

```
private void openWinMerge(string leftFile, string rightFile)
        {
            string args = "/C /f *.xml " + leftFile + " " + rightFile;
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinMerge\\WinMergeU.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            if (p.Start())
            {
                p.Dispose();
                return;
            }
        }
```

This is where I call the function calling `Process.Start()`. None of the code below `openWinMerge()` runs.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtSerial.Text.Length == 9)
            {
                PO.Number = txtSerial.Text.ToUpper();
                PO.SerialSearch = true;
                if (PO.Search())
                {
                    txtPO.Text = PO.Field.ProductionOrderNumber;
                    search();
                    createFolders();
                    copyDefaultFiles();
                    copyBackupFiles();
                    openWinMerge("\"" + Path.Combine(path, "INITIAL") + "\"", "\"" + Path.Combine(path, "Default") + "\"");
                    copyFinalXML();
                    return;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Serial");
            } else if (txtPO.Text.Length == 12) 
            {
                PO.Number = txtPO.Text.ToUpper();
                if (PO.Search())
                {
                    txtSerial.Text = PO.Field.SerialNumber;
                    search();
                    createFolders();
                    copyDefaultFiles();
                    copyBackupFiles();
                    openWinMerge("\"" + Path.Combine(path, "INITIAL") + "\"", "\"" + Path.Combine(path, "Default") + "\"");
                    copyFinalXML();
                    return;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid PO or Missing Serial");
            } else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter either Serial or PO of Analyzer");
            }
        }
```

**Update:**

I wrote some other code below `openWinMerge()` and it runs, so my issue is in `copyFinalXML()`

Here is the code for that

```
private void copyFinalXML()
        {
            try
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(path,"INITIAL"));
                Task.Delay(200);
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    // Will not overwrite if the destination file already exists.
                    string[] folders = file.Split('\\');
                    string filename = folders[folders.Length - 1];
                    if (filename.Equals("config.xml") || filename.Equals("service.xml") || filename.Equals("system.xml"))
                    {
                        string d = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(path, "FINAL"), filename);
                        File.Copy(file, d);
                        Task.Delay(500);
                        openNotePad(d);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Catch exception if the file was already copied.
            catch (IOException copyError)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(copyError.Message);
            }
        }



 private void openNotePad(string filename)
        {
            //Process.Start("C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe", "\"" + filename + "\"");
            Process.Start(@"notepad++.exe", "\"" + filename + "\"");
            return;
        }
```

Comment: What does `CreateNoWindow = true` do?

Comment: Why dispose a newly started process?   Are you expecting that the process has exited?  ...because it likely hasn't exited yet.  You should call `p.WaitForExit();`  And use a using statement rather than disposing manually.

Comment: Can you provide a command line, that you can paste to a console and WinMerge really opens correctly - because in https://manual.winmerge.org/en/Command_line.html I do not see any /C parameter!

Comment: @mjwills.  Possibly one of us is misunderstanding.  Could be me!  :)  (The question is not very clear) From what I gather, winmerge outputs a file to disk.  copyFinalXML likely tries to read that file before winmerge finishes writing it.  In debug mode, single stepping likely gives the process that split second it needs to finish the work.  So waiting for winmerge to complete before proceeding seems necessary.  Disposing it or not is irrelevant, but is a sign that Preston possibly believes the process has completed at that point, which it has not.

Comment: if timing is the real issue, how about launching the process in a separate task and awaiting it?

Comment: @Peston Pegram: Additionally you wrap " always around the file paths with `"\""` that is only ok/usefull if there is a space in the path, else not, I wrote a helper method for that, containing: `return parameter.Contains(" ")? $"\"{parameter}\"": parameter;` - and this works only if you do not have " in the paths itself ;-). What about the Winmerge.exe path, does it work in C# having spaces there without wrapping it in "  - or only the parameters need that?

Comment: Can tell me someone why the `p.WaitForExit();`were downvoted? It is the solution, and it was said that while debugging it works. That confirms it, after starting the process, we hang in the breakpoint and the process has enough time to complete in the mean time.

Comment: @BitLauncher because it blocks the main thread, for a non blocking solution you have to run the process on a separate task and then wait for the process there while awaiting the main method call and probably showing a loading indication or something.

Comment: @HMZ In the documentation of Process.start() it is written, that this method does not wait until the process has finished, so it does not block.

Comment: @BitLauncher i meant the `WaitForExit` method see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @PrestonPegram Do I understand your use case right? the user enters either serial number or PO, with button "Start" it completes the value not entered (PO.Search() method) and then it should open WinMerge and it closes immediately..shortly(?) after it has written the xml file, this file you copy - and then? You need a feedback in UI when the whole thing is over? Or can somebody click the start button the same time while winmerge processes the same entries already? Or should it be hindered? - Perhaps we best get it running, before background tasks are added etc.

Comment: @mjwills. I apologize. This project is for work and I posted the question right before leaving. I will try to get a minimum reproducible example to you guys soon.

Comment: @BitLauncher Yes. User enters a PO or serial, then search finds some other info about the order. All I intend for the program to do is open winmerge with the specified files for the user. After that I just need to copy some other files and open up notepad++. I do not need feedback when this is over though.

Comment: @mjwills . Create no window = true is supposed to hide the command line when this is used to open the command line. I just added this in attempt to solve my issue, but it does not work. path is a file path that the user chooses.

Comment: @Wyck You were correct. It was a timing issue. I thought that I was getting around this by using Task.Delay(), but I was not using await Task.Delay(), so there was not any actual delay.

Answer (score -1):

Add `p.WaitForExit();` to your code just before the code you want to execute after it finishes running the process.